# GoogleApiClient get Profile without asking user to login

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-client

I am calling the GoogleApiClient Api in order to get some basic Profile information about the current user (e.g. Gender).

Can I accomplish this without asking the user to explicitly login?

Here is my code:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .setAccountName("myemail@example.com")
                .build();
```

I then call `mGoogleApiClient.connect();`

onConnectionFailed gets called, with this message:

```
GoogleApiClient: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{2148816a: android.os.BinderProxy@549965b}}
```

I have these permissions set so far:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: did you put <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in manifest.xml

Comment: Yes I did, see above.

Comment: I want to avoid showing the Login popup at runtime.

Comment: Please visit. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker?hl=en It may help you.

Comment: The user has to explicitly login at least once, since they need to consent to giving permission to your app to get their information.  Subsequent times they launch your app will not have to explicitly login. (Unless the user explicitly logged out).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping this wouldnt be the case and the app level permissions during installation could cover this case.  I could get the right Google account with this code and then call the GoogleClientAPI AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
        Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();